# JavaFX - Giving WebView a URL through Scene Builder or NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, webview, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I'm a beginner at JavaFX.

I've made my layout in JavaFX Scene Builder. In that I've left a WebView but I cannot figure how to give it a URL.

In a separate class I've my WebView ready

```
public class GoogleApp extends Application {

private Scene scene;
MyBrowser myBrowser;

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
 }

 @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  primaryStage.setTitle("Railway Scenario Development");

  myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
  scene = new Scene(myBrowser, 800, 600);

  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.show();
}

class MyBrowser extends Region{

  HBox toolbar;

  WebView webView = new WebView();
  WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

  public MyBrowser(){

      final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("demo.html");
      webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());

      getChildren().add(webView);

  }

 }
 }
```

But I need to embed that in my application which I've made in Scene Builder. In Scene Builder there is a WebView Panel and I want that panel to look like the code I've mentioned above.

My application's code uses the fxml file as its "scene" (Shown below).

```
public class Railway extends Application {

private Scene scene;


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Railway Scenario Development");

    scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

I figure I've to do something in the FXMLDocumentController file. But how and what. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

now its work perfectly...try this

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
public class FXMLDocumentController {

@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private StackPane root;


@FXML
void initialize() {
    assert root != null : "fx:id=\"root\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
WebView view = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
    engine.load("http://www.google.com/");
    root.getChildren().add(view);
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't help. I already went through that file and couldn't figure my way out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to your first Version.

May others could try this: http://java-buddy.blogspot.de/2012/05/embed-webview-in-fxml-to-load.html.

It worked for me.

Here is an Example FXML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafxml_web.*?><!--- Important Use your own Package instead of "javafxml_web.*" --->

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="500" prefWidth="660" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxml_web.Sample">
    <children>
        <MyBrowser id="mybrowser" layoutX="10" layoutY="10" prefHeight="460" prefWidth="620" fx:id="mybrowser" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And in your Controllerclass you have to use:

```
@FXML
private MyBrowser mybrowser;
```

This should solve your Issues.